# lookup for a value in one column and return from another column's corresponding row in pands

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

*I know it is a fundamental question, but I couldn't solve it.
Any help will be appreciated*

My `list1` has around 1059 values, `list2` has around 7 values.

I want to check values in `list1` against values in `list2`, if matches append 'x' to `list variable`, if not matches append 'y' to same `list variable`. So at the end I want size of my `list variable` to be equal to the size of `list1`.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\Dynamo\dummy.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
list2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\Dynamo\dummy.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet2')

list2=((list2.dropna(subset=['Positionsnummer'])).drop_duplicates(subset=['IPositionsnummer'])).reset_index()

value=[]
for i in range(len(list1)):

    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1["ID"][i] == list2["Positionsnummer"][j]:
            value.append(list2['New Bewehrungsgehalt'])
            break
        else:
            value.append(list2['Bewehrungsgehalt'])
            break
```

But I am not getting as I wanted. I tried using break, continue everything, but it is not working.

- When using break, it's appending 'y' 6 times when it is not matching
- When using continue, appending '*I don't know*' many times.

*[Please find the image and script in the edited post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA1qe.png)
I hope this can help to understand my issue.*
I have 1058 recordsin `list1[ID]` which is equal to one in `list2['Positionnummer']`, So when both equals I want to get corresponding value from `list2['New Bewehrungsgehalt']` and append to out output list i.e `value`, if not equal append old(default) value to the list `value`. At the end I want `len(list1)` == `len(value)`.

> For example: in first iteration when `U1.ST.XX` from `list1[ID]` ==
> `U1.ST.XX` from `list2['Positionsnummer']` then `value.append(New Bewehrungehalt) i.e '88888888'`

Comment: Are your `list1` and `list2` are of type --> python `dataframe` or python `lists` ?

Comment: could you do only one for loop `for value in list1:` and then just have a `if value is in list2["Postitionsnummer"]:`? trying to control breaks/continues within nested loops is a hard task to do

Comment: Hi @Abhi, both are dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Example Solution

```
import pandas as pd
  
list1 = pd.DataFrame()
list2 = pd.DataFrame()

list1['ID'] = range(10)
list1['Bewehrungsgehalt']= range(10)
list2["Positionsnummer"] = [4,5,1,3]
list2['New Bewehrungsgehalt']= [4000, 5000, 1000, 3000] 
 

value = []

for i in range(len(list1["ID"])):
    if list1["ID"][i] in list(list2["Positionsnummer"]):
        new_val = list2[list2["Positionsnummer"]==list1["ID"][i]]["New Bewehrungsgehalt"].tolist()[0]
        value.append(new_val)
    else:
        old_val = list1['Bewehrungsgehalt'][i]
        value.append(old_val)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1000, 2, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\Dynamo\dummy.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
list2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\Dynamo\dummy.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet2')

list2=((list2.dropna(subset=['Positionsnummer'])).drop_duplicates(subset=['IPositionsnummer'])).reset_index()

value = []

for i in range(len(list1["ID"])):
    if list1["ID"][i] in list2["Positionsnummer"]:
        my_index=list2["Positionsnummer"].index(list1["ID"][i])
        value.append(list2['New Bewehrungsgehalt'][my_index])
    else:
        value.append(list2['Bewehrungsgehalt'][my_index])
```

Comment: It looks working, can I append value from another column for the corresponding matching row instead of appending "both match"? such as `value.append(list2["volume"][i])` To do this do I need the index value of matching row? or how can I get the value from exact row but different column?

Comment: if `list2["volume"]` has the same length of `list1` where each value in `list1` corresponds to a value in `list2["volume"]` then Sure you can. else if it is not the case then `index out of range` will occur

Comment: I don't think so index out of range happens.

The issue is straight forward, I want to compare each value from `list1` against available values in `list2` and get a value from another row corresponding to the matching row.

Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned the `value.append("x")`, I think it is creating confusion

Comment: please find the edited post, I have attached an image with sample data and also edited the question.

Comment: I understand you now. I updated the answer please check it and if it solves your problem consider marking my solution :)

Comment: The dummy example I provided is what I understood from your question. Tell me if it is not what you want

Comment: That's not the suitable solution. In this case index out of range occurs as `list1` has range of 1058 but `list2` has range of 6. As per your solution,  when the `i=1000` iteration `list1[ID][1000] == list2[Positionsnummer][1000]` is ambiguous because there is no `1000` value available in `list2`

Comment: I see. can you print list2 and provide a screenshot for it in your Question?

Comment: The Screenshot has been added. Please find the hyperlink in the task description. The image consists of whole list2, but partial list1(it's len of 1058)

Comment: I meant to see what the output in your terminal but anyways check my edited answer and tell me if it works